# Pulse oximeter gives no reading above 2000 Metres

Tags: gear

Just out of curiosity I bought a cheap pulse oximeter. So cheap that it does not even have a visible brand.

I tried it when I went hiking. I started from a height about 800/900 metres. Until 1800 / 2000 meters it worked well. But when I reached the top of the mountain (2290m) it did not give any reading. I tried a couple of times, then I thought that with the cold the blood flow to the hands was not strong enough, so I shelved it until summer and I tried it again, but I got the same result. It does not do anything special it just behaves as if it was reading nothing. Does anybody know why?

BTW I am aware that pulse oximeters are considered <s>unreliable</s> not precise at high altitudes.

Comment: If it still works at low altitude then your first and final sentences may apply.

Comment: Related https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21718156/

Comment: @WeatherVane Please do not misinterpret. Unreliable reading does not mean no reading at all. I already saw some pulse oximeters work and I also so one giving readings above 4000m.

Comment: IMO "not working at high altitude" would be included in a definition of "unreliable". Were the ones you saw working the same cheap unbranded model that you have? This looks distinctly like a "send it back" situation. BTW please don't be rude to commenters who [suggest something](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/29126/pulse-oximeter-not-working-above-2000-metres#comment75151_29126) that you did not mention.

Comment: Perhaps it's a great brand that would rather report nothing than give an inaccurate reading at altitude.

Comment: My in-laws lived at over 2290m and their cheap pulse oximeter worked just fine for them. Maybe not quite as cheap as yours. I have had no issues with mine (live at 1800m and regularly go over 2300m) which was off the shelf at the pharmacy.

Comment: I guess it can't detect your pulse because of vasoconstriction, it's just the low sensitiveness of the sensor, which doesn't need to mean low precision....

Comment: My pulse oximeter works at 12,000 feet (3,658 meters) and gives a reasonable reading.  "Cheap" may be the clue.  Mine cost around $80.00 a few years ago.  It is the CVS house brand.  CVS is a large chain pharmacy in the US.